# How to join generate_series and an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I want to generate a list of columns using `generate_series()` and joining it to a specific array (a list of value, e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`), and my expected result looks like this:

```
Day        | Code
2019-08-01 |  1
2019-08-02 |  1
2019-08-03 |  1
2019-08-01 |  2
2019-08-02 |  2
2019-08-03 |  2
2019-08-01 |  3
2019-08-02 |  3
2019-08-03 |  3
```

This query:

```
SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2019-08-01'
                     , timestamp '2019-08-03'
                     , interval  '1 day') AS DAY, 1 AS CODE;
```

will give me the result:

```
Day        | Code
2019-08-01 |  1
2019-08-02 |  1
2019-08-03 |  1
```

Then how to update the query to get the expected result?

Comment: I don't see the *array* you mentioned in your query. And please always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of many to produce your desired result *exactly*:

```
SELECT day::date, code
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2019-08-01'
                     , timestamp '2019-08-03'
                     , interval  '1 day') day
CROSS JOIN unnest ('{1,2,3}'::int[]) code;  -- using an actual array here
```

The point being: you need a `CROSS JOIN` to produce a Cartesian Product.